# Android - I don't get the output I want

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-2.2-froyo

I don't manage to get my emulator working, it shows the menu screen but it doesn't go through the screen with "your total is 0' and add button, substract button, I'm following that tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUA_isgpTHI&list=EC2F07DBCDCC01493A

Here is a screen of my avd parameters:

- avd name: brixon
- device: 5.1 wvga(480x800:mdpi)
- target: android 2.2 - API level 8
- CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi)
- Keyboard: checked
- Skin: checked
- front camera: none
- back camera: none
- memory options: ram: 512 vm heap: 16
- internal storage: 200 Mib
- SD Card: size (nothing)

On the launch options:

- skin: 480x800
- density: medium (160)
- scale display to real size: NOT checked
- wipe user data: NOT checked
- launch from snapshot: checked
- save to snapshot: checked

It's my code, I follow strictly the tutorial:

```
package com.grolard.newboston;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. **/

    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What i am doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.grolard.newboston"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.grolard.newboston.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Close your emulator and restart it again.. if it doesn't work then delete the current avd and create new one

Comment: Code is good, so don't bother with that. You have a problem with emulator, check on console whether your app is deployed and installed on emulator at all. Did you forgot to set launching activity?

Comment: What's in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: I tested your code on my galaxy and it works! try to build another emulator.

Comment: Ok guys,


blackbelt: my problem is that I don't manage to have what is shown in the minute 5:10, I just see the "home page". 

pragnani: I have done that, nothing special happened.

marko: How do I do that?


Jarvis: As I said, I have tried to build another one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Android device, connect it with usb cable and do the debug directly on the device. The emulator is slow and behaves in a strange way sometimes.

Comment: Hello Gleb, I don't have one, how can I "debug" the problem? It's pretty frustrating to not find a logical answer. And my android skills are pretty nooby.